# application created using Qt 5.3 doesn't work on windows 7 virtual machine

Tags: c++, qt, angle

***SOLVED***
: The issue was not related to the application but the VM itself. Created a new VM and it worked as expected. Thanks guys for the inputs. Much appreciated.

I have created an application using Qt 5.3 ANGLE version. It works fine on Windows, mac and Linux systems. The problem is when i try to run the .exe file in Windows 7 Virtual machine, it crashes.

Can anyone tell me the solution for it. Following is the screenshot of the error message.

Please note that I have included libraries mentioned in the error message .

[image]

Comment: This is likely a bug in the virtual machines graphics implementation. I am not using QtQuick myself so am not using OpenGL. Could you specify the vendor and version of the virtual machine software?

Comment: This is not a crash. It tells you exactly what's wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: @ Kuba Ober I have provided all the .dll files inside the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Provide the listed missing DLLs to your VM installation and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have provided all the DLLs needed for the application. Is there something else that I am missing ?

Comment: Are you sure? It is complaining about specific DLLs missing like d3dcompiler and libEGL.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have added libEGL, libGLESv2, d3dcompiler_47 .dlls

Comment: Still same error? Than I have no idea. It worked for us that way.

Answer (score 0):

Because your VM emulate a video graphic card. If you want to make this running this way, you have to pass through your 2nd graphic card (because you need one for the host and one for the guest, the second one drivers need to not be installed on the host) with the VM (consider Qemu/KVM would be the best one for do it well for free).

Then by this way, your VM will use a real graphic card and use the real dll driver for this card to. Also, like that can use the OpenGl function of the card (then, the VM not use it... It emulates one sometimes, but never be able to do the same job a direct graphic card can do).